# Drag event prevent mouse event

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, dom-events

When I'm select text and start to drag selections, mouse event like a wheel or mousemove doesn't fire. How I can catch an event while dragging?

I create a test example to check this issue, you can see it here:
https://jsfiddle.net/prevolley/3q7xwa8p/4/

```html
<p>dasdasdasdas</p>
```

```
document.addEventListener('wheel', (event) => {
  console.log('wheel', event.deltaY);
});
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
  console.log('mousemove', event.pageX);
});
```

I want to catch a mouse event while I drag selected text.

An image where I show the problem:

[image: imgur.com/a/gqBAVCz]

Answer (score -2):

you can use event `drag`:

```js
document.addEventListener('drag', (event) => {
  console.log('drag', event.pageX);
});
```

```html
Text
```

Comment: I don't want to catch a drag event. I want to catch mouse events when I drag selected text.